# Make div child scrollable inside 100% height parent div

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries, angular-material

I've tried to find a solution to this seemingly simple issue, but with no luck. I'm using AngularJS and Angular Material.

**index.html**

```
<div class="parent" layout="column" layout-fill ng-view>
</div>
```

**Example HTML template:**

```
<div class="child" layout="column" layout-fill>
    <div flex="20">
        Some content
    </div>
    <div flex>
        Some more content
    </div>
</div>
```

(There's nothing in the **parent** and **child** CSS classes, used just for name reference here)

In case the content is shorter than the screen height, I want both parent and child divs to be full height and the content divs to expand according to the flex properties. The **layout-fill** directive from Angular Material adds the 100% height, so this is currently working.

In case the content is longer than what can be displayed withing the screen height, I would like the child div to be scrollable.

My idea was to use media queries to append class properties to the child div in case height is below say 400px.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 400px){
.child{
        height: 400px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The child height is the same as the parent (screen height). When inspecting the element (Chrome) it says that css height is 400px, but the computed height is not.

I really don't understand that.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dgs5c0f/7/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the settings in the media query to

```
  child {
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
```

That forces it to be as high as its content and at least 400px, which will scroll in the body.

https://jsfiddle.net/zy0o7jn6/1/